# Can I use React Native with MariaDB?

Tags: react-native, mariadb

I start with React Native since few days and Want to know if I can use MariaDB with React Native instead of MySQL? I searched google but can't found any answer.
I will be so happy if I get the answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MariaDB is binary compatible with MySQL.
Some linux distros actually come stock with MariaDB so a lot of people don't even realise they're using it. So yes, please do use MariDB

Comment: Thanks for the answer